# How to connect multiple MQTT clients to single iothub via JMeter

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to establish connection of multiple MQTT clients to single azure server via JMeter.

Note:  all client ID's & all username's are different but sharing the common password(SAS)

client ID-1 connection snapshot: 
[image]

clinet ID-2 connection snapshot: 
[image]

and it goes on..

Now the problem is when I run the in thread, first client only get connect : 
[image]

& the other clients connections are throwing the error:

[image]

Anyhelp would be grealy appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you follow this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device

Comment: Yes tried the same. but the response are:                                                                 
for the 1st MQTT client: Response message: Connection org.fusesource.mqtt.client.CallbackConnection@97047d established successfully. For the 2nd MQTT client :Response message: Connection org.fusesource.mqtt.client.CallbackConnection@97047d is already established.

Comment: How did you create the password? The document shows the following format: **SharedAccessSignature sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}** Have a look at the *sr*, where this resource uri has a deviceId.

Comment: Also, can you use another MQTT client such as **MQTTBox**? http://workswithweb.com/html/mqttbox/downloads.html

Comment: SAS - I have generated using " host string" from iothubonwer in shared access policy page in azure portal. So the Password(SAS) is common for all the MQTT clients.  That the policy will grand access to each of iothub endpoints. And also, yes with mqttbox I can connect multiple MQTT clients with single password (SAS). But my test run includes multiple MQTT clients, let's say 50, , inturn each would  publish multiple payloads/ second with unique data. So jmeter is convenient to integrate with CSV file config & publish the data. Pls suggest if we have similar option in mqttbox. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use it, but try the following: http://workswithweb.com/html/mqttbox/mqtt_load_test_settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down by each virtual user so you don't need to duplicate this `Gateway Connect` sampler, just define 2 threads (virtual users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and each thread (virtual user) will execute `Gateway Connect` sampler and establish its own connection with the broker.

The credentials can be parameterized using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each virtual user would connect with its own username/password combination

More information: [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide/)

Comment: I have created two threads, each holding one connection sampler & three publishers. But I want to run two threads in parallel. Any suggestions pls. Earlier I have tried using two gateway connection sampler under single thread, but they sharing the common connection & most of the publisher data's get lost. Likewise I have 100 threads so when I start execution by unchecking the run sequential box in test plan, the jmeter  get collapse due to heap size.